# Why the structure sheaf of $\operatorname{Spec}k$ consists of $k$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field. Then $\{0\}$ is the only prime ideal of $k$. Therefore $\operatorname{Spec}k$ has only one point. $k$ has two ideals: $\{0\}$ and $k$. The set of all prime ideals containing $\{0\}$ is $\{ \{0\} \}$. The set of all prime ideals containing $k$ is $\emptyset$. Therefore $\operatorname{Spec}k$ has two closed sets: $\{ \{0\} \}$ and $\emptyset$. Hence $\operatorname{Spec}k$ has two open sets: $\emptyset$ and $\{ \{0\} \}$. But why the structure sheaf of $\operatorname{Spec}k$ consists of $k$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you mean $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(k)}(\{0\})=k$ (the structure sheaf also contains $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(k)}(\emptyset)=0$). This follows easily from the definition of the structure sheaf (if you use the definition in Hartshorne's book: Compute $k$ localized at its unique prime ideal $0$, but this is $k$). More generally, if $A$ is any commutative ring, then ring of global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}$ is $A$.

Comment: thank you very much. But I am confusing. When we define a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, we only need open sets and for each open set $U$, $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is a ring satisfying some conditions. It seems that we do not need localizations.

Comment: Please sit down and look at any of the usual definitions of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$.

Comment: it seems that $k$ localized at $0$ is $0$ since for each $(a,0), (b,0) \in k \times \{0\}$, $0(a\cdot 0 - b \cdot 0)=0$.

Comment: Localising at $0$ is very different from inverting $0$!

Comment: Recall that $A_{\mathfrak{p}} := (A \setminus \mathfrak{p})^{-1} A$. Thus, if $A$ is an integral domain and $\mathfrak{p}=0$, this is the field of fractions. When $A$ is already a field, this is just $A$ itsself.

Comment: @ZhenLin, thank you very much. It is said in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring that localization at $S \subseteq k$ is $0$ if $0 \in S$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, thank you very much. I understand now.